# in vim, how to keep search pattern (second to last search pattern, not last search) in a buffer and use it in a new search?

Tags: search, vim, verilog

suppose I have 3 idential files xfile1.txt, yfile2.txt and zfile3.txt with following contents.

```
mane
hind-leg
shell
```

and I also have a file test.txt like below.

```
xfile1.txt
{
lion mane
}

yfile2.txt
{
rabbit hind-leg   // line 8
}

zfile3.txt
{
turtle shell
}
```

I want to make a macro by defining `q, my-macro-key, my-wanted-key-sequences, q` and using it with `@, my-macro-key` for the following operation.  What I want to do is, when my cursor is placed for example, in the middle of `hind-leg` in line 8 of `test.txt` file, when I press a macro key like `@, z`, to make it open yfile2.txt and place my cursor at the beginning of `hind-leg` in the new open file.
So for recording the macro, I placed my cursor at the middle of hind-leg in file test.txt and pressed `q,z,b,*,ctrl-o,?,^,{,enter,k,g,f,*` (start macro recording for charter `z`, goto beginning of the word, search forward, come back, reverse search for `^{`, go up a line, enter the file(yfile2.txt), search for the pattern again. for those who don't know what the previous sequence is..). but the last '`*` searches for '^{' because that is the last search patter that I used until that point. I want to use the search pattern `hind-leg` in the new opened file.
How can I use the old search pattern `hind-leg` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Recalling previous searches

You can recall previous search patterns in the *command-line* by pressing <kbd>↑</kbd>.

Alternatively, if you want a list of previous search patterns to select from, you can enter the *command-line window* via `q/`. This is a full Vim buffer, so you can navigate with `j` / `k`, even search with `/`, and edit previous patterns in the usual way. Press `<Enter>` to select the current line's pattern.

#### Storing search patterns elsewhere

You can paste the current search pattern in a (scratch) buffer via `"/p` (`"`: select register, `/`: search pattern register, `p`aste). Unfortunately, you cannot simply `y`ank back to the search register, but this will do:

```
:let @/ = getline('.')
```

Alternatively, you can also use other registers to store the pattern. For example:

```
:let @a = @/
" Recall later
:let @/ = @a
```

And there's the `histget('/')` function to access previous search patterns.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I tried using `/+uparrow` during the recording and it works!